# Burn a disk image to a USB

Tags: dd, usb-drive, boot-loader, disk-image, burning

I'm following [this](http://dc0d32.blogspot.com/2010/06/real-mode-in-c-with-gcc-writing.html) guide to make a simple bootloader. It generates a file `disk.img`.

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=1024 count=1440
$ dd if=vbr.bin of=disk.img count=512 conv=notrunc
$ file disk.img
disk.img: DOS/MBR boot sector
```

Running `qemu-system-i386` and `qemu-system-x86_64` on `disk.img` boots fine, displays the desired text.

I want to be able to boot my *actual* PC into this "operating system". I figured I could simply run:

```
$ dd if=disk.img of=/dev/sdc1
```

...and reboot my PC, selecting `Boot from USB` at the BIOS, but I get this error:

```
Invalid partition table!
```

However, running `qemu-system-i386 /dev/sdc` and `qemu-system-x86_64 /dev/sdc` works fine.

How do I write `disk.img` to my USB stick so that it will boot from my actual BIOS?

Comment: I believe that your error is that you are writing `disk.img` to `/dev/sdc1` instead of to `/dev/sdc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the steps I took to create `disk.img` make it so that `disk.img` can only be properly written to a floppy. However, eliminating the image file entirely (writing directly to the USB) worked (make sure you're using `/dev/sdX` instead of `/dev/sdXY`):

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdc bs=1024 count=1440
$ dd if=vbr.bin of=/dev/sdc count=512 conv=notrunc
```